# Getting Column does not exist Error when using SUBSTR function in derived column

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, vertica

I have two tables named "Customer" and "Contract" .

Query:

```
    Select 
   cu.A||cu.B||Co.C||Co.D as DUMMY,
    (SUBSTR(DUMMY,25,1) as NEND,
    SUBSTR(DUMMY,1,19) as MDATE
    from Customer Cu
    Left Outer Join Contract Co
    on Cu.A=Co.D
```

So, when am running this query, am getting error like "DUMMY column does not exist"

Can anyone please help me how to implement this.

Comment: Error itself is very clear there is no dummy column, so please use same combination of columns inside SUBSTR in place of DUMMY.

Comment: You have an extra opening parenthesis in your query.

Answer (score 2):

The `DUMMY` is an alias, so it cannot be referenced on the same query as you have done.

If you want to use the `DUMMY` alias like that, you have to make the entire query as subquery. Then you can use the `substr` function, like so:

```
select dummy,
  substr(dummy,25,1) as nend,
  substr(dummy,1,19) as mdate
from (
  select
    cu.a||cu.b||co.c||co.d as dummy
  from customer cu left outer
    join contract co on cu.a = co.d
);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to using subqueries or CTEs is to define the column using a lateral join:

```
select s.DUMMY,
       SUBSTR(s.DUMMY, 25, 1) as NEND,
       SUBSTR(s.DUMMY, 1, 19) as MDATE
from Customer Cu left join
     Contract Co
     on Cu.A = Co.D left join lateral
     (select cu.A || cu.B ||C o.C || Co.D as dummy
      from dual
     ) s
```